# Self activation for customer portal access

Tags: customer-portal

I would like to allow existing contacts without customer portal access enabled to self activate themselves using a form. As contacts dont have passwords set, would it be possible also set their password at the same time or atleast have a 'reset password' email sent to them.

How can I implement such a feature? Does the self registration function create new contacts or simply updates the existing ones? My requirements are that the contact must already exist within SF.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you download [Getting Started with Communities](http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf). See the section in the PDF titled "Setting Up Self-Registration for External Users".  You must customize the
CommunitiesSelfRegController and optionally, the CommunitiesSelfReg page. You must specify in the default controller which account the self-registration process should assign users to. You can also specify a profile, but it will override the default selected when enabling self-registration.

You begin the process by:

1. From Setup, click Customize > Communities > Manage Communities.
2. Click Edit next to your community, then click Login Page.
3. Select Allow external users to self-register to enable self-registration for your community.

Then continue following the instructions in the PDF.

Comment: Isn't Communities something different all together?

Comment: No, communities are like enhanced portals or portals on steroids. If you don't already have existing portal licenses, only new community licenses are available. If you're building a new portal using existing licenses, I recommend you build a community instead (your licenses will allow you to do either). You get built-in chatter, branding and other feature enhancements for free. Self Registration for a portal works the same as for a community, but is accessed via a different menu. Apologies for the oversight.

Answer (score -1):

The user should have a role and should have "Create and Customize Communities" permission to activate contact for community so, so I don't think a contact without having the permission can enable it.

Comment: If my comment was wrong then please provide right thing, which helps me.

Comment: see my answer above